# Can I create a new entry in a Rails db by posting XML data in lieu of form data?

Tags: xml, curl, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm playing with a very simple contacts Rails app. I have a /contacts route that I can POST to add entries in the contacts table (using scaffold). I want instead to send XML data in the POST (rather than FORM data) using XMLHttp Request. The request works, but the params object in Rails doesn't show the data I sent (debug with .inspect).

Here is my curl commmand:

curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @contact.xml -X POST http://www.acme.com:3000/contacts

and the contact.xml file looks like:

```
<contact>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <email>joe@acme.com</email>
  <phone>+12148622544</phone>
</contact>
```

This corresponds to the fields in the contacts table exactly.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Uinsg Rail 4

Comment: Does the params object have any values?

Comment: This is what it looks like: {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"contacts"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the XML parser was removed from ActionPack in Rails 4. You can add it back in using the gem here: [actionpack-xml_parser](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-xml_parser). Doing so will parse XML into your params hash.

**UPDATE:**
It would appear that the Rails team's implementation of this gem kills the actual XML in the body of the request when it parameter-izes the XML into the `params` hash. This fork keeps the XML in the body as it (in my opinion) should be:
https://github.com/mxrguspxrt/actionpack-xml_parser

Answer (score 0):

I thought Rails automatically parsed xml into a `params` hash but it dosen't seem that is the case.

You should be able to parse the sent xml manually. Your controller should look something like this:

```
def new
  xml = request.body.read
  params = Hash.from_xml(xml)

  # do something with params hash...

end
```

A few things to look out for:

- The request my fail if a CSRF token is not passed (if `protect_from_fogery` is set). You can get round this with the callback `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`
- The `params` hash will not work with symbols. You will need to access params like this: `params["contact"]["name"]`

Comment: I'm probably better off populating a form element with the names and their values from the XML document in the client. But now, at least, I know why :)